fastest way for getting concurrent entries in large database
i need to get concurrent sessions for every minute of day from database with ~2 million rows. what is the best(fastest) way to get that data?
table contains session_id, session_start_time, session_end_time
example
CREATE TABLE `session_id_table` (
  `session_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `session_start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `session_id_UNIQUE` (`session_id`),
  KEY `idx_session_id_table_session_id` (`session_id`),
  KEY `time_1` (`session_start_time`,`session_end_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin;


insert into session_id_table(session_id, session_start_time, session_end_time) values 
(1, '2024-09-05 10:00:23', '2024-09-05 10:15:54'), 
(2, '2024-09-05 10:00:29', '2024-09-05 10:22:54'), 
(3, '2024-09-05 10:01:23', '2024-09-05 10:26:54'), 
(4, '2024-09-05 10:02:20', '2024-09-05 10:21:54'), 
(5, '2024-09-05 10:02:23', '2024-09-05 10:20:54'),
(6, '2024-09-05 10:21:00', '2024-09-05 10:35:54') 

result should be
'2024-09-05 10:01:00', 1 
'2024-09-05 10:01:00', 2 
'2024-09-05 10:02:00', 1
'2024-09-05 10:02:00', 2
'2024-09-05 10:02:00', 3
'2024-09-05 10:21:00', 2
'2024-09-05 10:21:00', 3
'2024-09-05 10:21:00', 4
'2024-09-05 10:21:00', 6

so for every minute of day it needs to show active sessions at that time.
first i tried to do join for small part of data for 2 days (~30k rows per day, 300-700 session_ids per minute)
select distinct date_format(a.session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i'), b.session_id 
from session_id_table as a
left join 
session_id_table as b
on date_format(a.session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i')>=b.session_start_time and date_format(a.session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i')<=b.session_end_time
and date(a.session_start_time)>'2024-09-05'

but query didnt execute even after 3 hours

I do nit really understand this question! In both cases the queries are executed by mysql, not by python. If you write performant sql queries supported by the right indexes, then mysql will return results fast regardless of the client. Your first query cannot use any indexes for filtering because of the way you wrote the expressions. That probably explains why that query is slow. We can probably help you to optimise the query, but you need to share the underlying data structure, show some sample data and expected results, and share the explain output for your query.

added data example. i need all active sessions per every minute of day.

And what about the rest?

added create table and further clarifications

Thanks, thiese help a lot! What's the point of the criteria with date formats in your firt query?

to get datetime without seconds. then i can check what sessions are active for every minute.

don't understand how the 'result should be'  correlates with the sample data provided,  i presume second column is the count of 'active sessions' in that minute ... yet there appears to be duplicate entries ... are you missing an 'as at timestamp' .....

this is not count, but active session_id for that minute. in 10:01 i had 2 active sessions(session_id 1 and 2), in 10:02 i had 3 active session_id(1, 2, 3) etc.
this is just sample data, but i have enough data to get every minute for every day. results just show what query should give for data sample.

Session_id 1 starts at 10:00 and ends at 10:15. Why doesn't the output have 15 rows for session_id 1 - 1 for every minute session 1 was active as your requirement seems to state?

this is just data example so it doesnt represent actual situation. whole table has rows for every minute of every day, so fetching them with "select distinct date_format(a.session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i')" represents easy way to get every minute without complicating stuff in actual table. when i use same select on provided data example here it behaves differently.

wanted to do answer this 3 days ago, but when benchmarking i noticed weird results(that i posted in another thread).
anyways fastest way to get concurrent session id-s is through comparing timestamps that are in another table. comparing datetimes on join gives 20-35% slower results than with timestamp. indexing data that is used on join argument seems to slow down everything not on the edges of database(added first or added last).
select dt, session_id from datetime_timestamp as a
inner join session_id_table as b 
on (dt>=session_start_time) and (dt<=session_end_time)
#where dt>='2023-05-25 00:00:00' and dt<='2023-05-25 01:00:00'
where dt='2023-10-25 00:00:00' and dt<='2023-10-25 01:00:00'
#where dt>='2023-12-10 00:00:00' and dt<='2023-12-10 01:00:00'
#where dt>='2024-09-10 00:00:00' and dt<='2024-09-10 01:00:00'
#where dt>='2024-09-20 12:00:00' and dt<='2024-09-20 13:00:00'


compared to same query with datetime instead of timestamps

if we use CTE with timestamps:
with 
dates as
(select distinct convert(date_format(session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i'), datetime) as date_time, unix_timestamp(convert(date_format(session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i'), datetime)) as ts
from session_id_table)
select date_time, session_id from dates as a
inner join session_id_table as b 
on (ts>=start_ts) and (ts<=end_ts)
#where date_time>='2023-05-25 00:00:00' and date_time<='2023-05-25 01:00:00'
where date_time>='2023-10-25 00:00:00' and date_time<='2023-10-25 01:00:00'
#where date_time>='2023-12-10 00:00:00' and date_time<='2023-12-10 01:00:00'
#where date_time>='2024-09-10 00:00:00' and date_time<='2024-09-10 01:00:00'
#where date_time>='2024-09-19 00:00:00' and date_time<='2024-09-19 01:00:00'

we get these execution times

if we run same CTE query but just have join on datetime instead of timestamps we get these results:

when i started this thread with python+sql script i needed to run ~55 seconds for every hour of data in database, but i could run this concurrently for faster execution.
with answer from d r i got ~5 seconds execution time when i tested it, giving the query significant improvement, but i didnt test this extensively.
2 weeks after, i decided to benchmark new query after learning where i failed in OP, saw weird results, run d r query saw weird results, so i created new thread about that weirdness. overall indexes gave super fast results at beginning of the table, but much slower results at anything not at edge, so d r answer was slower than python+sql solution that i already had for over 90% of the table.

What is "d r"??

Which table is dt in?

You'll need to generate rows for every minuute in the day in order to get all active session ids in every minute. Using recursive ctes could be helpfull here:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
CREATE TABLE `session_id_table` (
  `session_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `session_start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `session_id_UNIQUE` (`session_id`),
  KEY `idx_session_id_table_session_id` (`session_id`),
  KEY `time_1` (`session_start_time`,`session_end_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin;

insert into session_id_table(session_id, session_start_time, session_end_time) values 
(1, '2024-09-05 10:00:23', '2024-09-05 10:15:54'), 
(2, '2024-09-05 10:00:29', '2024-09-05 10:22:54'), 
(3, '2024-09-05 10:01:23', '2024-09-05 10:26:54'), 
(4, '2024-09-05 10:02:20', '2024-09-05 10:21:54'), 
(5, '2024-09-05 10:02:23', '2024-09-05 10:20:54'),
(6, '2024-09-05 10:21:00', '2024-09-05 10:35:54');

WITH    -- C T E (s)
  recursive log_hours  As
    ( Select 0 as hrs 
     Union All
      Select hrs + 1 as value
      From log_hours
      Where  log_hours.hrs < 23
    ),
  hrs_mins AS
    ( Select  Concat( LPAD(h.hrs, 2, '0'), ':', LPAD(m.mins, 2, '0') ) as hr_min 
      From    log_hours h
      Left  Join ( WITH 
                     recursive log_mins  As
                       ( Select  0 as mins 
                        Union All
                         Select  mins + 1 as value
                         From    log_mins
                         Where   log_mins.mins < 59
                       )
                   Select * From log_mins
                 ) m ON ( 1 = 1 )
      Order By  h.hrs, m.mins
    ), 
  dates AS
    ( Select   CONVERT( DATE_FORMAT(s.session_start_time,'%Y-%m-%d'), DATE ) as dt,
               Min(CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(s.session_start_time,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%i:00'), DATETIME)) as min_dt_tm,
               Max(CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(s.session_end_time,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%i:00'), DATETIME)) as max_dt_tm
      From     session_id_table s
      Group By CONVERT( DATE_FORMAT(s.session_start_time,'%Y-%m-%d'), DATE )
    )

--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select       s.session_id, 
             Date_Format(s.session_start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') as session_date,
             hm.hr_min as session_hour_minute
From         dates d
Inner Join   hrs_mins hm ON( 1 = 1 )
Inner Join   session_id_table s ON( CONVERT( DATE_FORMAT(s.session_start_time,'%Y-%m-%d'), DATE ) = d.dt And 
                                    hm.hr_min >= Date_Format(s.session_start_time, '%H:%i') And 
                                    hm.hr_min <= Date_Format(s.session_end_time, '%H:%i')
                                  )
Where      CONVERT( Concat(DATE_FORMAT(d.dt,'%Y-%m-%d'), ' ', hm.hr_min), DATETIME ) >
             ( Select min_dt_tm From dates Where dt = CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(s.session_start_time, '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE) ) And
           CONVERT( Concat(DATE_FORMAT(d.dt,'%Y-%m-%d'), ' ', hm.hr_min), DATETIME ) <=
             ( Select max_dt_tm From dates Where dt = CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(s.session_start_time, '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE) )
Order By   Date_Format(s.session_start_time, '%Y-%m-%d'), hm.hr_min, s.session_id

/*      R e s u l t :
session_id  session_date    session_hour_minute
----------  --------------  -------------------
         1  2024-09-05      10:01
         2  2024-09-05      10:01
         1  2024-09-05      10:02
         2  2024-09-05      10:02
         3  2024-09-05      10:02
......      .......         .....
         2  2024-09-05      10:16
         3  2024-09-05      10:16
         4  2024-09-05      10:16
         5  2024-09-05      10:16
......      .......         .....
         2  2024-09-05      10:22
         3  2024-09-05      10:22
         6  2024-09-05      10:22
         3  2024-09-05      10:23
         6  2024-09-05      10:23
......      .......         .....        */

Addition:
First, ( @asd asd ) I'd like to thank you for your correction of my initial typos - been working on something similar (not same) and did some copy-paste actions without (or with incomplete) corrections. Thanks.
It is important to say that I'm not, in any way, someone who has some special knowledge about mysql - quite the opposite, I've never done a single job using mysql - the most of my jobs were (and are) tied to Oracle. On the other hand - the rdbms engines, no metter how different they could be, have a good deal of common things...
The answer to the question in coments why is this code faster than the one from question - well, there are a fair few of the reasons which you can find listed below and check using the link to the fiddle at the end. The list is not sorted in any order of significance and should be taken as a collection of some general rules and practices that were used in this answer to make this thing working a bit faster:

the code is adjusted to use the indexes provided in OP's create table statement
cte(s) used, with the exception of dates cte,  are completely separated from the data - no tables were used (see the fiddle below)
recursion for hours and nested recursion for minutes generate a row for every minute in a day which is used as a predefined grid of rows for any posible date/day/period that exist in your data
code doesn't depend on implicite datatype conversions - if there is a  date comparison needed - it is compared to another date datatype explicitely - timestamp to another timestamp
all together, properly combined, made the code running a bit faster then the code from the question - the actual data from your table are processed with already prepared grid of all minutes in a day cross joined to all dates of interest with no conditions whatsoever ON(1=1).

EXPLAIN plans for every part/step of the code used in this answer could be seen in the fiddle here.

thanks for extensive answer. at first look this solution has ~10-20x speed improvement over my other solution in python+sql and probably over 1000x improvement over solution in OP. although you had some small mistakes that i have edited.

i dont understand how it achieved such big speed improvement. instead of recursive function i used select distinct date_format(session_start_time) which should fetch basically all datetime for my interest. is search by separate date and time faster than search by datetime? or is it cause of date_format(session_id) breaks search through database?

just finished checking if it gives correct data and it is 99% there. this query doesnt catch active session from previous day, so data is always off by ~5-10k rows. will dissect query later to understand whole logic and try to understand how you achieved those improvements.

@asdasd Just posted an addition and a link to the fiddle. Hope this could help you get the picture of the lolgic that made this thing a bit faster ...

A PRIMARY KEY is a UNIQUE KEY is a KEY -- so drop the two redundant indexes.

Think about using GROUP_CONCAT() when forming the output -- instead of one line per session.
