how to decrease fetch time
i have made relatively simple join query for selecting data for one hour of data on 3 values in large table(2+ million rows), but depending on time selected, fetch time drastically increases

first query has option that selects data from start of the table, second is somewhat near start and last is near end of the table.
create statement
CREATE TABLE `session_id_table` (
  `session_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `session_start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `session_id_UNIQUE` (`session_id`),
  KEY `idx_session_id_table_session_id` (`session_id`),
  KEY `time_1` (`session_start_time`,`session_end_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin;

insert into session_id_table(session_id, session_start_time, session_end_time) values 
(1, '2024-09-05 10:00:23', '2024-09-05 10:15:54'), 
(2, '2024-09-05 10:00:29', '2024-09-05 10:22:54'), 
(3, '2024-09-05 10:01:23', '2024-09-05 10:26:54'), 
(4, '2024-09-05 10:02:20', '2024-09-05 10:21:54'), 
(5, '2024-09-05 10:02:23', '2024-09-05 10:20:54'),
(6, '2024-09-05 10:21:00', '2024-09-05 10:35:54') 

result for such data should be:
'2024-09-05 10:01:00', 1 
'2024-09-05 10:01:00', 2 
'2024-09-05 10:02:00', 1
'2024-09-05 10:02:00', 2
'2024-09-05 10:02:00', 3
'2024-09-05 10:21:00', 2
'2024-09-05 10:21:00', 3
'2024-09-05 10:21:00', 4
'2024-09-05 10:21:00', 6

with 
dates as
(select distinct convert(date_format(session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i'), datetime) as date_time 
from session_id_table 
order by convert(date_format(session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i'), datetime))
select date_time, session_id from dates as a
inner join session_id_table as b 
on (date_time>=session_start_time) and (date_time<=session_end_time)
#where date_time>='2023-05-25 00:00:00' and date_time<='2023-05-25 01:00:00'
#where date_time>='2023-10-25 00:00:00' and date_time<='2023-10-25 01:00:00'
#where date_time>='2023-12-10 00:00:00' and date_time<='2023-12-10 01:00:00'
#where date_time>='2024-09-10 00:00:00' and date_time<='2024-09-10 01:00:00'
where date_time>='2024-09-19 00:00:00' and date_time<='2024-09-19 01:00:00'

created functional index for one function used in CTE, got these results:

created single indexes for session_start_time and for session_end_time and got these results:

is this mysql configuration issue? index issue? or query issue?
explain

idx_time_1 is index on (session_start_time, session_end_time)
idx_time is index on (session_id, session_start_time, session_end_time)
idx_convert_time is index on ((convert(date_format(session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i'), datetime)))
idx_start is index on (session_start_time)
idx_end is index on (session_end_time)
here is explain json for fastest query
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "208534400.08"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "a",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 973,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 973,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "14.66",
            "eval_cost": "97.30",
            "prefix_cost": "111.96",
            "data_read_per_join": "15K"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "date_time"
          ],
          "materialized_from_subquery": {
            "using_temporary_table": true,
            "dependent": false,
            "cacheable": true,
            "query_block": {
              "select_id": 2,
              "cost_info": {
                "query_cost": "1411.11"
              },
              "ordering_operation": {
                "using_filesort": false,
                "duplicates_removal": {
                  "using_filesort": true,
                  "cost_info": {
                    "sort_cost": "973.00"
                  },
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "session_id_table",
                    "access_type": "range",
                    "possible_keys": [
                      "idx_time",
                      "idx_time_1",
                      "idx_start",
                      "idx_convert_time"
                    ],
                    "key": "idx_convert_time",
                    "used_key_parts": [
                      "cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime)"
                    ],
                    "key_length": "6",
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 973,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 973,
                    "filtered": "100.00",
                    "cost_info": {
                      "read_cost": "340.81",
                      "eval_cost": "97.30",
                      "prefix_cost": "438.11",
                      "data_read_per_join": "2M"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                      "session_id",
                      "session_start_time",
                      "cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime)"
                    ],
                    "attached_condition": "((cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) >= '2023-05-25 00:00:00') and (cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) <= '2023-05-25 01:00:00'))"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "b",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "possible_keys": [
            "idx_time_1",
            "idx_end",
            "idx_start"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 2143170,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 231654145,
          "filtered": "11.11",
          "range_checked_for_each_record": "index map: 0x70",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "3847.12",
            "eval_cost": "23165414.57",
            "prefix_cost": "208534400.08",
            "data_read_per_join": "503G"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "session_id",
            "session_start_time",
            "session_end_time"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

here is for explain slowest

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "200390348.15"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "a",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 935,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 935,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "14.19",
            "eval_cost": "93.50",
            "prefix_cost": "107.69",
            "data_read_per_join": "14K"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "date_time"
          ],
          "materialized_from_subquery": {
            "using_temporary_table": true,
            "dependent": false,
            "cacheable": true,
            "query_block": {
              "select_id": 2,
              "cost_info": {
                "query_cost": "1356.01"
              },
              "ordering_operation": {
                "using_filesort": false,
                "duplicates_removal": {
                  "using_filesort": true,
                  "cost_info": {
                    "sort_cost": "935.00"
                  },
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "session_id_table",
                    "access_type": "range",
                    "possible_keys": [
                      "idx_time",
                      "idx_time_1",
                      "idx_start",
                      "idx_convert_time"
                    ],
                    "key": "idx_convert_time",
                    "used_key_parts": [
                      "cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime)"
                    ],
                    "key_length": "6",
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 935,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 935,
                    "filtered": "100.00",
                    "cost_info": {
                      "read_cost": "327.51",
                      "eval_cost": "93.50",
                      "prefix_cost": "421.01",
                      "data_read_per_join": "2M"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                      "session_id",
                      "session_start_time",
                      "cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime)"
                    ],
                    "attached_condition": "((cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) >= '2024-09-10 00:00:00') and (cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) <= '2024-09-10 01:00:00'))"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "b",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "possible_keys": [
            "idx_time_1",
            "idx_end",
            "idx_start"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 2143170,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 222607015,
          "filtered": "11.11",
          "range_checked_for_each_record": "index map: 0x70",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "3845.46",
            "eval_cost": "22260701.56",
            "prefix_cost": "200390348.15",
            "data_read_per_join": "484G"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "session_id",
            "session_start_time",
            "session_end_time"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

here is also explain analyze for fastest
-> Nested loop inner join  (cost=6.69e+6 rows=7.43e+6) (actual time=15.4..346 rows=20827 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on a  (cost=539..541 rows=31.2) (actual time=8.61..8.64 rows=61 loops=1)
        -> Materialize CTE dates  (cost=539..539 rows=31.2) (actual time=8.61..8.61 rows=61 loops=1)
            -> Group (no aggregates)  (cost=535 rows=31.2) (actual time=7.7..8.5 rows=61 loops=1)
                -> Sort: date_time  (cost=438 rows=973) (actual time=7.69..7.76 rows=973 loops=1)
                    -> Filter: ((cast(date_format(session_start_time,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) >= '2023-05-25 00:00:00') and (cast(date_format(session_start_time,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) <= '2023-05-25 01:00:00'))  (cost=438 rows=973) (actual time=0.191..6.67 rows=973 loops=1)
                        -> Index range scan on session_id_table using idx_convert_time over ('2023-05-25 00:00:00' <= cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) <= '2023-05-25 01:00:00')  (cost=438 rows=973) (actual time=0.189..6.44 rows=973 loops=1)
    -> Filter: ((a.date_time >= b.session_start_time) and (a.date_time <= b.session_end_time))  (cost=28.4 rows=238082) (actual time=5.14..5.52 rows=341 loops=61)
        -> Covering index range scan on b (re-planned for each iteration)  (cost=28.4 rows=2.14e+6) (actual time=0.0733..4.28 rows=8709 loops=61)

and for slowest query
-> Nested loop inner join  (cost=6.56e+6 rows=7.28e+6) (actual time=1375..76261 rows=21064 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on a  (cost=518..520 rows=30.6) (actual time=25.6..25.7 rows=61 loops=1)
        -> Materialize CTE dates  (cost=518..518 rows=30.6) (actual time=25.6..25.6 rows=61 loops=1)
            -> Group (no aggregates)  (cost=515 rows=30.6) (actual time=24.7..25.4 rows=61 loops=1)
                -> Sort: date_time  (cost=421 rows=935) (actual time=24.7..24.8 rows=935 loops=1)
                    -> Filter: ((cast(date_format(session_start_time,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) >= '2024-09-10 00:00:00') and (cast(date_format(session_start_time,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) <= '2024-09-10 01:00:00'))  (cost=421 rows=935) (actual time=1.2..23 rows=935 loops=1)
                        -> Index range scan on session_id_table using idx_convert_time over ('2024-09-10 00:00:00' <= cast(date_format(`session_start_time`,_utf8mb4'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i') as datetime) <= '2024-09-10 01:00:00')  (cost=421 rows=935) (actual time=0.477..22 rows=935 loops=1)
    -> Filter: ((a.date_time >= b.session_start_time) and (a.date_time <= b.session_end_time))  (cost=29.6 rows=238082) (actual time=1249..1250 rows=345 loops=61)
        -> Covering index range scan on b (re-planned for each iteration)  (cost=29.6 rows=2.14e+6) (actual time=0.216..968 rows=1.89e+6 loops=61)


Why converting session_start_time in order clause? order by session_start_time does the same.

Error Code: 3065. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'data.session_id_table.start_time' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

UNIQUE KEY session_id_UNIQUE (session_id) this is excess , since you have PRIMARY KEY (session_id).  order by convert(date_format(session_start_time, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i'), datetime) is useless as long as limit is not used.

What are you trying to achieve as it seems to me that is overcomplicated. Please add some data examples and expected result

What is the query supposed to do? Please explain with some sample data and expected result.

this is query to get concurrent session id for every minute in a day. for e.g. '2024-09-20 00:00:00' it gives me all session_id that are currently in progress(started before 00:00 and ended after 00:00).

added example data.

this seem to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78960944/fastest-way-for-getting-concurrent-entries-in-large-database

this is actually question related to fetch time and not about query/specific problem. i have problem understanding why fetch time is so much different for data in middle of table. i suspect that this is configuration issue with database and not query issue.

I would do it differently... use a calendar table that stores 1 second intervals between x and y; and use a simple left join. Currently you have a where clause that uses a function (convert + date_format) so it has to do a full table scan before it can evaluate where clause.

i am using CTE to get all "date HH:MM" relevant to my query in datetime. i dont see how calendar would improve execution when it would basically do the same thing. btw where clause is only there to benchmark different parts of the data for execution. i would be using this to populate insert, but i have noticed slowdown depending on when i select data. beginning of the table is super fast for ~same amount of data, while towards the end is 100x slower in duration and 200x slower in fetch.

btw i also used functional index for it and you can see improvement in second picture. it did nothing for fetch.

This question is similar to: fastest way for getting concurrent entries in large database. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

well i got my answer although it confuses me.
TLDR; index can slow down queries. more about it here. mysql can also slow down with indexes that will not slow down postgreSQL or SQL server, more about it here. query with no index gets me 3-4 times performance improvement for over 90% database, while i see index improvement only on queries that fetch data from edges of database.
decided to experiment if timestamps would be faster solution, so i moved all datetime and ts into a new table and added start_timestamp and end_timestamp in session_id_table. results with CTE in OP and datetime in new table were same. then i tried same query with timestamps i got consistent results for all 5 queries in overall duration(duration+fetch) compared to difference of 100x or 200x in duration/fetch time that i got with CTE/datetime and results improved for most of the table(not for edges). decided to create indexes for timestamp and results were comparable to results in OP. so deleted indexes and got overall improvement in fetch time.
just disclaimer, changed 5th query from OP
where date_time>='2024-09-19 00:00:00' and date_time<='2024-09-19 01:00:00'

to
#where dt>='2024-09-20 12:00:00' and dt<='2024-09-20 13:00:00'

here is data for table
those 5 queries without indexes provide these results

here is those 5 queries with only session_start_time index

here is those 5 queries with separate session_start_time and session_end_time index

here is those 5 queries with both session_start_time and session_end_time in one index

also you can see some improvement when using join on timestamps without index compared to datetime without index

here is more data when selecting one day of data with:
#where date(dt)='2023-05-25'
where date(dt)='2024-09-10'

join on timestamps no index

join on datetime with no index

join on datetime with session_start_time, session_end_time in one index


"TLDR; index will slow down select when doing join on multiple attributes. would be good if someone can further explain this(or if this is somewhat of an outlier)"   Where did you find this wisdom ?   Why do you think that could be true ?  What other assumptions did you have ?

well i did experiments with and without indexes on that query in database with 2+ million rows. unless you have some other explanation on why is this happening.

Sorry stil trying to reproduce the problem, but not for long, because info is missing.

i am confused with these results cause without indexes i get 3-4 times improvement for all queries that are not on the edges of database.

@luuk
well i googled this and got these topics link and link simply put it is not index on multiple attributes, but just general index can slow down queries.
